# Table not published beyond one page

Tags: tables, longtable

Why is this table not spanning two pages ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\textheight 21.0 cm
\topmargin 0 cm
\textwidth 16 cm
\oddsidemargin 0.0 cm
\linespread{1.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{notation}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.33\columnwidth}|p{0.33\columnwidth}|p{0.33\columnwidth}|}
\hline
Notation &Meaning \\
\hline
$\mathbb{Z}(d)$ & Integers modulo d. \\
$H(d)$ & Hilbert space d \\
$\Pi(d)$ & Finite geometry  \\
$\Gamma$ & Cell \\
 $X$&  Position .\\
$P$&  Momentum . \\
$D(z)$ & Dis \\
${\cal P}$ & Pa \\
${\cal W}$ &  Function \\
${\cal {\tilde W}}$  & W function \\
$ |X;a\rangle$ & position state \\
$ |P;a\rangle$ & momentum state \\
$S(\beta)$ &  transformation \\
$ |X \rangle$ & set \\
$B$ & origin \\
${\mathfrak L}(1,2)$ & `F \\
$|{\mathfrak X}(x,y)$ & Weak mutually unbiased bases \\
$\Theta(u, \tau)$ & Theta function \\
$\varphi(N)$ & Line of  \\
${\mathfrak K}(a,b)$ & set\\
${\mathfrak Z}(a,b)$ & parallel lines  \\
$ \varphi (d)$& Euler totient function of $d$. \\
$\sigma_1 (d)$& Divisor function to power $1$ of $d$.\\
$ a \prec b$ & $a$ is  partially ordered in $b$.\\
$ a\cong b$& $a$ is isomorphic to $b$.\\
$\mathcal{Z}_d$ &integer modulo $d$. \\
$\{ \mathcal{D}(d) \} $& set of non-trivial divisors of $d$. \\
$ A\subseteq B$ & A is a subset of B. \\
$a \leq b$ & a is less than or equal to b. \\
$x$ & y \\
$x$ & y \\
$x$ & y \\
$x$ & y \\
$x$ & y \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the `tabular` environment with `longtable`, i.e. `\begin{longtable}`